# subclass name is a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, attributes

I can use SimpleNamespace to turn a dictionary into an object:

```
>>> a = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
>>> b = SimpleNamespace(**a)
>>> b.foo
1
>>> b.bar
2
```

Which is great. However, I run into a strange issue if one of the keys in the dictionary is a number:

```
>>> a = {"foo": 3, "1": "hello"}
>>> b = SimpleNamespace(**a)
>>> b.foo
3
>>> b.1
Syntax Error
```

Which makes sense since variable names can't start with a number. However, if I run:

```
>>> dir(b)
['1', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'foo']
```

It still shows '1' as one of the entries. How is this possible? Is there a way to acces this index?

Comment: `getattr(b, '1')`

Comment: It is an *attribute*, not a subclass.